# Nodemon Giving Trouble

Tags: nodemon

my nodemon is not able to save changes that I make to my server code and it breaks whenever I save any changes. can you help me out? I'm attaching some screenshots to better explain the problem

[image]

Comment: It would help if you installed a dev logger package like Morgan so you can see which endpoint you are requesting and thus make sure that there's not another console log with "hi" that you see and not the correct one. How do you test your endpoint?

Comment: this was a trial file, so there are no other endpoints that I can think of, also, this is the only change that I made since starting the server. the 'listening on port 3000' message also doesn't get printed on server restart.